# Flexslider2 Slider with Carousel Slider as Navigation

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I am using Flexslider2 with Carousel Slider as navigation here: http://sproutdesigns.co.uk/clients/pim/property.html

However when the thumbnail goes to the second slide it isn't adding the class "flex-active-slide". It is working on all other slides but not this second slide.

I can't see any errors occurring, so not sure why it is happening, can anyone help?

Here is the example I have based this upon: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html

Answer (score 0):

I Should have Googled the answer, looking on the Flexslder Github this was an issue: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/193 which seems to be fixed with an update of Flexslider to V2.2.2